# Modify Header Error

Tags: php

```
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 1 (if user attempts to add something to the cart from the product page)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0;
    // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
        // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    } else {
        // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                      $wasFound = true;
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
           } // close foreach loop
           if ($wasFound == false) {
               array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
           }
    }
    header("location: http://www.hirelogo.com/cart.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

I'm having an issue with understanding the error I'm getting. I've just recently switched to VPS with a newer version of PHP if that helps. This is the error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/hirelogo/public_html/cart.php:5) in /home/hirelogo/public_html/cart.php on line 40
```

line 40 being

> header("location: http://www.hirelogo.com/cart.php");

Any help in understanding this is much appreciated. Another note. This issue wasn't occurring before the switch.

Comment: ob_end_flush(); something I tried to alleviate the problem.

Comment: Make sure there's nothing before `<?php`, since it will be sent before running the code.

Comment: remove that flush, and as @Barmar said remove all white space before that

Comment: @Chris Yes that will cause PHP to send headers and start trying to send output. Either remove it or put it after your `header()` function, the "modify header" error will tell you at what line started the conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that *"something"* is being pushed to the client before headers are written.

1. Check if any BOM (Byte Order Mark) is causing the issue, which might well be the case if you use UTF-8 or UTF-16.
2. Check all code from the start of the request file, down to the very last include until the script hits the error, and make sure there is no output (like `echo` or `sprintf`) before you push out the headers.

Comment: I just removed it and its working, but the same thing happend before. After a while it kicked out. I'm not sure what I was doing for it to occur so it's very tough to replicate.

Comment: @Chris Glad to hear you solved your problem. For future reference, keep in mind to never push anything to the client *before* you push out headers; headers *always* have to come first. Too bad you had to find out the hard way, but at least now you know… ;)

Answer (score 1):

If header() is called on line 40 then you have something in your document before the first line of the code you have posted. Because I have header as being on line 29 of your code.

You cannot output anything at all before calling header() post anything you have before the `<?php` start tag

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
```

Try to change the following code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || (isset($_SESSION['cart_array'])  && count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1)) {
```

Notice the error you're appear maybe?

Comment: Its not needed, PHP will run `count( $_SESSION["cart_array"] )` if only `$_SESSION["cart_array"]` exists